# Add total price in checkout success page

Tags: magento

I need to know, if any solution how to add in magento success.phtml order's total price?
Because I want after placed order, customer get all info how to make payment including what price need to pay, because customer don't remember in last step what is total price.

Comment: please search this has been answered before here

Comment: you talking about this one?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927685/magento-checkout-success-page-product-price-and-sku-retrival

this one don't work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use something like this in your `success.phtml`:

```
$sOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
$oOrder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($sOrderId);
echo $oOrder->getGrandTotal();
```

Comment: This is a terrible answer. You could easily accidentally show someone elses order if 2 orders came through with miliseconds of each other. Use `$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($this->getOrderId());` instead.

Comment: @dotty: The `last_order_id` is saved in the PHP session when the user clicks 'Buy'. The PHP session id is bound to the browser of a specific user, usually by cookie. Mind to explain, how a value read from a user specific session should lead to show the order of a different user?

Answer (score 10):

in success.phtml template you can use

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
$total = $order->getGrandTotal();
```

proper way is to extend the `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Success` and add your own method for loading the order again (As in this page quote is inactive already) as it is not nice to load such stuff in templates

Comment: This is the actual answer that is safe, unlike the selected answer.

Comment: I get a total value of 0.000 with this every time. Magento 1.9